# How to display values into gridview from sql databese

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, dataset

In my database i have three tables. One For employs where i keep their names, ids, salary... In the second one named Project i keep id, location, name. in the third one named WorksOn i keep the id from employs and the id from project. In my Asp .Net web site in gridview i need to display the employee's name and the name of the project that he is working.

```
  string connect = 
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
    try
    {
    con.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
    string error = err.Message;
     con.Close();

    }


   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    command.Connection = con;


    SqlDataReader reader;

    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM WorksON ";
    reader= command.ExecuteReader();
```

In data source in gridview if i choose to display the values from WorksOn table it shows the id from employs and the id from project but what i need is to show the names on the employs and project.
I know that i need to do something with dataset but i don't know who.

Comment: Sounds like you need to [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) from the WorksON table to the employee information table.

Comment: Plz share the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL command must JOIN the related tables. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM WorksOn JOIN Employee on WorksOn.EmployeeId = Employee.Id
```

Note that you should *not* SELECT "*" (all columns). You should only SELECT those columns that are necessary to your data view for performance.

Answer (score 0):

On your SQL command, you don't mention anything about Employs.  You need to use a JOIN SQL command in order to get both the employee name and the company name.

And instead of using "SELECT * FROM...", consider using the columns name instead, because you're not trying to get all the columns display.  And it will help us understand the name of the columns to further help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN query like this:

```
SELECT project.projectName, employee.Name
  FROM (worksOn
        INNER JOIN employee
           ON (worksOn.employeeId = employee.employeeId))
       INNER JOIN project
          ON     (project.projectId = employee.employeeId)
             AND (worksOn.projectId = project.projectId)
```